# WordPress and ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, iis, web-hosting

We have a Wordpress site being hosted. We want to build in a login link on the Wordpress site to open a different site written in ASP.NET.

We have hosted the IIS on a sub-domain, but our hosting package only allows 2 websites. Thus, Wordpress occupies 1 and IIS the other. So we not sure where to host the APS.NET site? Can it be hosted with Wordpress on the same domain and seen as 1 site, as the LOGIN URL will just point to the new home page to login?

I'm not a guru at this. New to ASP.NET, so don't want to pay for more website hosting.

Thanks.

Comment: IIS is a web server and you cannot host it. You can host your .NET web applications on IIS web server and IIS comes pre-installed on Windows based hosting servers. If your host only allows you 2 websites, you can host WordPres on one domain and .Net website in another domain.

Answer (score 0):

asp.net never works without IIS. IIS work as server. You have to host asp.net application inside IIS. Make it default in IIS, may be it will work as your need.